# JSP debugging in IntelliJ with spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp, intellij-idea

I want to be able to debug jsp templates in IntelliJ.

- I'm using Spring-Boot
- Project is without `web.xml` file. Made with Annotations.
- I'm launching app via Spring Boot run Configuration in IntelliJ
- When I launch the app, breakpoints become gray crossed circles, indicating that no class associated with it.
- Jsp location is `/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp`

Now, before I get marked for duplicate:

- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33739/jsp-debugging-in-intellij-idea) question is quite old and only suggest using `web.xml` + `Tomcat` and plugin. Pluggin doesn't seem to work and switching to `web.xml` is going to be a real pain in the bottom. Would be nice to stay with annotations and not include `web.xml`
- Tried launching via maven command as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23304921/debugging-jsp-with-spring-boot-and-intellij) answer, but for unknown reason, after launching, the process detaches from intellij and I'm not able to launch it again (have to destroy process in the process task first) and it doesn't resolve the issue either.
- Other answers, suggesting launching Tomcat directly fail as it won't launch without `web.xml`.

How can I keep an ease and speed of launching Spring-Boot application, have an ability to hot-swap the code, debug java and jsp templates while avoiding `web.xml` configuration all at the same time?

Comment: Same boat here.  I submitted a ticket to JetBrains and they replied: "JSP debugging is supported only for the app server configurations like Tomcat in IntelliJ IDEA.

You can build your app as a war, deploy it on Tomcat and use Tomcat run/debug configuration for JSP debugging."